# Conditionally render a DOM element in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I tried using if/else and same problem
**JSX**

```
return ( 
     <Layout>
           <>
            {data.map((service, index) => (
              { index % 2 === 0 ?
                 <div className="circle"></div>
                 :
                 <div className="square"></div>  
               } 
              ))
             }
        </>
      </Layout> 
  )
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: I think that you need to remove the parenthesis after the fat arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code.

```
return ( 
     <Layout>
           <>
            {data.map((service, index) => {
              return index % 2 === 0 ?
                 <div className="circle"></div>
                 :
                 <div className="square"></div>  

              })
             }
        </>
      </Layout> 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

For a much cleaner alternative:

```
  return ( 
     <Layout>
       {data.map((service, index) => (
         <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'circle' : 'square'}></div>
       ))}
      </Layout> 
  )
```

Comment: I guess i didn't put the full code, but the problem is that the content structure on the inside needs to alternate but based on my example this is correct

Comment: To add, this is perfect if you only wanted to toggle css classes

Comment: I actually ended up doing somethign toggleing classes and handeling stuff on the scss side but i wanted to do it how to do it without

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
const elementSet = data.map(( service, index) => ((index % 2)===0) ? (<div className="circle"></div>) : (<div className="square"></div>) );
return ( 
       <Layout><>
        {elementSet}
       </></Layout>
);
```